# protect comments from unclosed tags

Tags: php, laravel, strip-tags

So I'm using strip_tags to allow fromatting to users familiar with html. The problem is that `<strong>my comment doesn't have strong closing tag` makes the rest of the page bold.

Is there a function to add all the missing tags at the end of string? How do I cure this?

Comment: Are you saying that strip_tags is removing the </strong>?

Comment: No I'm saying '<strong></strong>' is on the white list, but there's nothing preventing user from using just opening tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the loadHTML() and saveHTML() methods.

```
$somevar = new DOMDocument();
$somevar->loadHTML("$somestring");
echo $somevar->saveHTML();
```

This should clean up any sloppy html in the string you're pulling in by inserting closing tags.